# Does Spring @Async work with Client-Server communication?

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

I've read Spring's documentation about @Async, and it's not clear to me whether this is supposed to work only when the caller and the called service are in the same JVM.

I have a Spring web app deployed on a Tomcat, and a Swing application, using Spring HttpInvoker for communication between those two. I want to call server services from the client and return the results asynchronously. Do I have to build something else, or can I use @Async?

When testing this in the same JVM, it worked. When testing it with 2 JVMs, I got

> java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.concurrent.FutureTask

on the server, which implies that I cannot use this mechanism with two JVMs.

Any ideas?

Of the many tutorials I found concering @Async, none seems to cover the case of remote calls and return values.

Comment: I don't understand. `@Async` is an annotation you can use on a method. When processed by Spring, any invocation of the method (from the proxy) will be invoked asynchronously. You can only invoke the method within a JVM, so I don't know where the second comes into play or where your confusion lies.

Comment: Talking about a remote call from a client to a service on a server, where the service is annotated with @Async. The client would get a Future as result and would have to ask the Future object whether the service has finished yet, in order to deliver the service results from server to client. Server+Client = 2 JVMs.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no relation between two JVMs.

You're using a client that sends HTTP requests to an HTTP server which then responds with an HTTP response. That's all there is to it.

Spring's `@Async` annotation is meant to indicate that a method should be run in an asynchronous context. This has absolutely no relation to an HTTP client. This is a method that is invoked within the web application.

The error you are getting has to do with how you invoke the method and how you try to send an HTTP response to the client. You're pretty much comparing apples to oranges when saying that it works with one JVM versus two JVMs. The JVMs don't matter. What matters is that in one case, you are invoking the method. In the other case, you have a client/server setup where the server fails to serialize some entity to the HTTP response.

Comment: I dunno what the big misunderstanding is here. You can annotate a method in one application, and the method gets executed in a new thread, asynchronously. The caller gets a Future object to wait and receive the final result.

If I annotate a remote service and call that remote service via HTTP request, then that request goes to the server, where the call is returned immediately, and the service runs in a new thread. But the Future object I receive on the client is not serializable.

I am trying to use the async method call mechanic in a client server communication. My question: should it work?

Comment: @Lessing There is no misunderstanding with that. You're getting a `NotSerializableException`. You seem to be trying to serialize the `FutureTask`. That is an issue unrelated to a client/server architecture.

Comment: @Lessing It depends on how you are trying to serialize it. But you'll need to provide more details as to what you want to do. What you've described doesn't make much sense. It seems like you want an asynchronous client.

Comment: EJB's @Asynchronous can do this: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tejb_clientcode.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F3-3-0-11-1-4-3&lang=en

Can Spring's Async do the same?

Comment: @Lessing I'm pretty sure that in that document, _client_ refers to some other java code running in the same application. You seem to be referring to an HTTP client talking to your HTTP server (the tomcat webapp).

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's what I wanna do. There is no indication in the Async documentation about whether it works if you send a Future object to a remote client. In the ibm link, you can clearly see that they talk about a real remote client calling an EJB server. I want to do the same via HTTP with Spring.